# apache rewrite rules are not working after adding proxy pass

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, apache2.2

i am trying to rewrite the url in apache which internally redirect the requests to apache tomacat

Here is my httpd.conf code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/myapp/my.html
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/myapp/my.html

    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ http://localhost:8080/myapp/my.html?product=$1 [QSA]
 </IfModule>
```

so basically what i am trying to do is if i enter localhost/myapp then it should redirect me to localhost:8080/myapp/my.html

Next is if i enter the url localhost/myapp/8 it should redirect internally to localhost:8080/myapp/my.html?product=8.

Now the problem is ProxyPass is working absolutely fine. But the rewrite rule is showing 404 error.
If i remove the ProxyPass code then the same rewrite rule works but it shows the modified url in the browser. 
So i want to know where should i place RewriteRule to make it work with ProxyPass and y the rewrite rule is showing the modified urls?

Comment: I'm kind of stuck with this similar problem too. Do you have any solution?

Comment: No not yet. Please do inform if you ever get a solution for this. @david

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `[P]` flag to the `RewriteRule`. This causes the `RewriteRule` to 'proxy' the same way your `ProxyPass` directive does. At the moment your rule doesn't make any sense. Alternatively you could do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ /myapp/my.html?product=$1 [QSA,PT]
```

Which should cause the URL to be rewritten and then passed through (this happens because of the `PT` flag) to any remaining modules that need to process the URI path, in this case the proxy module.

FYI the terminology is wrong, when you say `if i enter localhost/myapp then it should redirect me to localhost:8080/myapp/my.html` you really mean `if i enter localhost/myapp then it should proxy to localhost:8080/myapp/my.html`. A redirect is an external response which cases the browser to request a new URL and the text in the browsers address bar will change.

Mind you, with your current configuration, requesting `localhost/` will proxy to `localhost:8080/myapp/my.html`. So if you can specify which is correct it would help.